# Can I rotate 3D car object

Tags: android, 3d

Can I use a rotating animation without using anyOpenGL or any 3rd pary tool. I just want to apply a clockwise rotating 3D car object in a fix layout.yout.

Comment: [Have you tried this?](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html)

Comment: Thats just a flip animation which resizes along the width, its not really a rotation as such.  You wouldn't get a view of multiple sides of a 3D object, only 2 sides of a flat object.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some sort of sprite animation sequence that emulates a 3D car then I don't see how you can do it to be honest.  I might be wrong though and may have missed something in android but to me this is a classic openGL situation.

By sprite animation I also mean any sort of 2D sequence of images, for example animated gifs.

Comment: It means You wants to tell Me that to use OpenGL is the best option for me to doing this type of task...???

Comment: In my eyes either you have to use OpenGL or you need to first animate outside of android (for example in blender/3dsMax/Maya etc) then take each frame and save it as part of a gif.

Comment: Using OpenGL will allow interaction from the user and allow them to rotate in any direction they wish, even zoom in and out if you let them.  Using gif they can interact but only to go forward and backward in the animation sequence.  It is more limited, so it is really a decision based on what you want the user to be able to do with the 3D model.

Comment: Sir, Can You please send me any open source example or any link for doing this if You have for testing purpose..?

Comment: which one? openGL or the gif based approach? Either way there are tonnes of resources out there, simple search on google for `android openGL tutorial` will guide you through the basics.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13928/discussion-between-maddy-and-jon-taylor)

Comment: Have you tried searching google? I am not going to send you any code on here, neither will others because what you are trying to do is not just a quick task.  You need to read up on openGL, read up on the way it works in android, look at how you can import a 3D model.  As I said there are plenty of resources out there and a simple search on google will come up with many examples.

Comment: OK... Thanks Sir..., I'll try with this. Thanks for the suggession

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Well, you first have to set the car in 3D space;
To model a 3D object, you must define all the vertices of the car as if you were modeling with points and after , linking this point you get the car in wireframe.


Pont  A {x = 3, y = 10, z = 8}
Point B {x = 5, y = 12, z = 2}
Point C {x = 6, y = 40, z = 6}
Point D {x = 7, y = 12, z = 3}
Point E {x = 3, y = 10, z = 8}
...

2) After modeling the car in points, you must define the links of points to form lines, there you have called wireframe modeling, if you want to modeling shapes is different, but with the wireframe already a good idea of the object in the real world.

Line AB = Point A -> Point B
Line BC = Point B -> Point C


3) To spin perfectly the car, you should position it in the center of coordinates,applying in each point the formula translation T with measure the match the distance to the subject from the center at the origin of the axes.

New point x:
x = x - Tx 
New point y;
y = y - Ty
New point z:
z = z - Tz


4) With the car in position to  spin it into an angle "g" should be applied to each point the rotation transformation, the formula is:
 
Find the new point x:
xt = (x * 1) (* y 0) (z * 0);
Find the new point y:
yt = (X * 0) (y * Math.cos (g)) (z * (Math.sin-(g)));
Find the new point z:
zt = (X * 0) (y * Math.sin (g)) (z * Math.cos (g));


5) After applying the rotation effect, you must return the object to its point of origin, making a reverse translation to step 3.

New point x:
x = Tx x
New point y;
y = y Ty
New point z:
z = z Tz


This is a  roughly explanation but is the most basic way, of course it has more complex formulas that are faster these changes, but to become more didactic I put this way.
```